# Gmail EventReservation markup disappearing

Tags: gmail, google-schemas, google-now

My `EventReservation` markup has been approved by Google but I'm noticing that at times, the `ViewAction` (a simple link) that I associated with it disappears from Gmail and I was wondering what could cause this problem.

Markup example:

```
{
   {
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"EventReservation",
    "reservationStatus":"http://schema.org/Confirmed",
    "reservationNumber":XXX,
    "url":"XXX",
    "action": {
      "@type":"ViewAction",
      "name":"Message Host",
      "url":"XXX"
    },
    "modifiedTime":"2015-08-13T17:56:29+0000",
    "underName": {
      "@type":"Person",
      "name":"XXX"
    },
    "reservationFor": {
      "@type":"Event",
      "name":"XXX",
      "image":"XXX",
      "startDate":"2015-08-17T10:42:28-0400",
      "endDate":"",
      "location": {
        "@type":"Place",
        "name":"",
        "address": {
          "streetAddress":"XXX",
          "addressLocality":"XXX",
          "addressRegion":"XXX",
          "postalCode":"XXX",
          "addressCountry":"XXX"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to generate a button with the EventReservation schema. You can generate a "View Ticket" button using a URL property:

```
"url": "https://example.com"
```

To get a "modify reservation" button, use the modifyReservation property:

```
"modifyReservationUrl": "https://example.com
```

In the example you've posted, I'm assuming you're trying to trigger a custom action label with the ViewAction schema. I was able to achieve this by defining a top level Event Reservation first then the View Action. My example below:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "123456",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Example Event",
    "startDate": "2015-08-17T14:30:00-08:00",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "AT&T Park",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
        "addressRegion": "CA",
        "postalCode": "94107",
        "addressCountry": "US"
      }
    }
  },
 "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "name": "View Event",
    "target": "https://www.example.com"
  }
}
</script>
```

The action button doesn't disappear and should stay:

[image]

Comment: I see. I actually edited the example to have properties in the same order they are in the actual application (and also the real markup has a `url` property, not sure if that might conflict) but I guess even then I would have to move the action all the way down. I was wondering about the difference between `action` and `potentialAction` though and how that matters

Comment: I have been noticing that when the markup shows, the event isn't added to the user's calendar and vice versa. Is that a known issue?

Comment: I'm able to generate my event into calendar. To my knowledge there is no known issue and I've never had any problems with the event not populating in a calendar. Try sending the basic example (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#basic_event_reminder_without_a_ticket) and change the date to today's date and your local time zone.

Comment: Just wondering, if `addressRegion` or `postalCode` are left blank, might that cause problems for the markup? It seems required in the docs but only recommended in the Google markup tester.

Comment: Those are actually "required" properties. Please see the specifications (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#specification). Make sure you have all required fields filled out. The minimal should be from this example (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#basic_event_reminder_without_a_ticket).

Answer (score 0):

json+ld markup is also removed by some eMail carriers.

I found Mandrill was removing my markup, until I changed the format from json+ld to microdata.